# abrt-ccpp.service: where are core files?

Tags: linux, dump

I'm newish to Linux and am learning about services, specifically abrt-ccpp.service for this question.

I've been led to understand that if abrt-ccpp.service is installed on a Linux PC, it supersedes/overwrites (I've read both, not sure which is true) the file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, which otherwise specifies the location and filename pattern of core files.

**Question**:

When I execute `systemctl`, why does abrt-ccpp.service report `exited` under the `SUB` column? I don't understand the combination of `active` and `exited`: is the daemon "alive" or not?

```
> systemctl
UNIT                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB
abrt-ccpp.service    loaded active exited ...
```

**Question**:

Where are core files generated? I wrote this program to generate a `SIGSEGV`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envz[])
{
  int* pInt = NULL;
  std::cout << *pInt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution as follows:

```
> g++ main.cpp
> ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But I don't understand where the core file is generated. It is not in the same folder as my `main.cpp`. [Some reading](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-abrt-configuration-abrt.html) led me to `/etc/abrt/abrt.conf`, which has the following text in my file:

```
# Specify where you want to store coredumps and all files which are needed for
# reporting. (default:/var/tmp/abrt)
#
# Changing dump location could cause problems with SELinux. See man_abrt_selinux(8).
#
#DumpLocation = /var/tmp/abrt
```

Thus I tried looking in `/var/tmp/abrt`, but there was nothing related to my `a.out`.

The contents of my `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` appear to have been overwritten with something related to abrt-ccpp:

```
> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e
```

But I don't know how to interpret this.

Can someone help me understand this service? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh, the solution is to edit `/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf` to add this line:

```
ProcessUnpackaged = yes
```